# django detect fixtures with m2m_changed signals

Tags: python, django, signals, m2m

I am having trouble to figure out whether my signal handler is called during fixture loading or not. Most of my signal handlers receive an extra keyword `raw` when django load fixtures. However, this extra keyword only get passed through when handling 'pre/post' signals, it doesn't get pass through if the signal I am listening to is m2m_changed!

Is there any reliable way to tell whether I am in a "fixture loading mode" or not with `m2m_changed`

Comment: Could you solve this in the last 8 years by any chance?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember! I've moved away from django to aiohttp and couldn't be happier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone found this just like me, one horrible, horrible way to solve this is the following:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8399#comment:7

In this old ticket of the django Project a way to determine whether a signal was triggered form a loaddata or not is requested.

After this, the `raw` keyword was the proposed solution, which does not appear in the `m2m_changed` signal. Before that there was the following proposed workaround, which still works:

```
try:
    from functools import wraps
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.functional import wraps

import inspect


def disable_for_loaddata(signal_handler):
    @wraps(signal_handler)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for fr in inspect.stack():
            if inspect.getmodulename(fr[1]) == 'loaddata':
                return
        signal_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

You can than use this decorater to disable any signal on loaddata, like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=models.Foo.bar.through)
@disable_for_loaddata
def some_signal(sender, instance: models.Foo, action: str, **kwargs):
    # signal code
```

Comment: The information in the link is prone to change. Could you quickly summarize what the link is about for us?